# Retrieve $_GET data from PHP cURL request (Strava Webhook)

Tags: php, api, webhooks, strava

I have spent countless hours trying to figure this out. I'm trying to integrate Strava Webhooks. This is a PHP based application that is going to be a WordPress plugin. The crux of the issue as I see it is that I'm sending data via a cURL request, but not getting the $_GET request back.

According to their documentation, I send a $_POST request (via URL) with a callback URL param. The API sends $_GET data back. I then return a JSON file with some data.

I have the JSON return code working successfully (there's a test for that). The problem is when I send the $_POST request, I can't seem to get the callback to send the $_GET data.

The documentation is pretty weak (https://developers.strava.com/docs/webhooks/) and the internet has left my high and dry.

I can post code if need be.

My questions are - is cURL not the best way to do this?
If there's no good way in PHP, can I used JavaScript?

Comment: Are you by any chance developing on your local machine? Just asking because the callback might not be able to reach you (if you are behind a NAT-router for example, like most usual home internet connections work)

Comment: That was the first few hours wasted. I am running it on a dev site that is on a server and is a full baked website.

Comment: I am trying to integrate the webhook through php for a long time and nothing so far, could I share your code?

Comment: @GeovaneKrüger - I picked this back up this week and got it working. I am going to create a gist in case you or anyone is interested in a solution. It's pure PHP and I tested it using a hardcoded file (but will clean that up).

Comment: Here's the gist that works to get the Webhook ID: https://gist.github.com/erikdmitchell/2e165c57e618de14e1b208fceba2ee65